# My simple for loop just doesn't work and I don't know why

Tags: c, for-loop, math

I'm trying to make a something which would just take a user generated input, place it into a matrix and just calculate the average across the rows.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int grades[5][5];
    float average;
    int i, j; 
    int n, m; // number of columns and rows
    printf("Enter the number of Rows then the number of Columns: ");
    scanf("%d %d", &n, &m);

    for(i = 0; i<=n; i++){
        for(j = 0; j<=m; j++){
            printf("Input the number for place %d %d -> ", &i, &j);
            scanf("%d", grades[i][j]);
        }
    }
    // the problem is that i keep getting wild input numbers... 
    // instead of i and j going 0 0, 0 1, 0 2... 1 0, 1 1, 1 2... 
    // it goes to like 2293320 2293316 and then does not move. 
    // (the huge numbers are the first and only outputs i get from the input numbers message)


    //this should be working
    for (i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        average = 0;
        for (j = 0; j <= m; j++) {
            average = average + grades[i][j];
        }
        average = average/5;

        printf("The average marks obtained in subject %d is: %.2f\n", i, average);
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Thank you for your help. :D

Comment: You need to describe *how it isn't working*.  We only know what your code does, not what you intended it to do.

Comment: Use `printf(..., i, j)` to print the values, instead of your current `printf(..., &i, &j)` which prints addresses

Comment: `i<=n` should be `i<n`. Same for `j`.

Comment: Turn up your warning level. Lines 14 and 15 produce warnings that might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you are seeing is caused by

```
printf("Input the number for place %d %d -> ", &i, &j);
scanf("%d", grades[i][j]);
```

If you compile with warnings (i.e. `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` on linux, not sure what on windows). You'll see a few warnings.

```
so60197534.c:14:49: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat=]
             printf("Input the number for place %d %d -> ", &i, &j);
                                                ~^          ~~
                                                %ls
so60197534.c:14:52: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat=]
             printf("Input the number for place %d %d -> ", &i, &j);
                                                   ~^           ~~
                                                   %ls
so60197534.c:15:21: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
             scanf("%d", grades[i][j]);
```

This is telling you that the values you are passing to `printf` and `scanf` do not match with the format string you provide.

For `printf` "%d" means an int value, but you provide an int pointer. So the simple fix is to take away the ampersands.

```
printf("Input the number for place %d %d -> ", i, j);
```

For `scanf` "%d" means an int pointer, but you provide an int. So we need to add an ampersand.

```
scanf("%d", &(grades[i][j]));
```

Now the warnings are gone and you get sensible values. There are other issues with your code but the one you ask about here is resolved.

Comment: It solved the problem, Many thanks. I bet there are other issues with the code but those will come in time. I just started learning 2 days ago. :)

Comment: Aha I see, so the problem is: I'm imputing the number of rows and columns (n,m) but the number is bigger by one because I start from 0? As for the average division I see, I forgot to chage the 5 to m (if that's what you meant). Thanks :D  The new comment updated for me just now... yeah thanks ex nihilo, I fixed it already the way you were saying.

Comment: Yeah... lol I was getting .00 all the time... didn't even see. I don't get why it does that... since the average is formatted as a float... it should calculate a float too and save the calculation in the float? It should be about the same so I have just placed the stuff in the printf("...same...", i, average/(float)m); at the end. Now it works fine and i learnt casting too lol. Thanks :D

Comment: Oof... now I know why I was getting .00 all the time. The stuff from before works just that I kept testing it with 2 2 in the matrix... thus usually getting nice pair sums while also dividing with m (which equals to 2 )XD. Sry for my sloppy commenting... still getting used to this forum. :)

Comment: @Cewu00 [here](https://ideone.com/CMrMS1) is what I did to your code. Doesn't seem relevant to post it in the answer, but I may as well share it.

Comment: @Paul Rooney, thanks. Yup, I can see, it fixes lots. I have already started complicating it even more tho :D. Now instead of having int values for the first number in the array you will have the names of subjects which will be represented in the print.  Still need to see if it is a buggy mess like this itteration was lol. Thanks again for your help. Really appriciate it.